# What is the best way to remove the sieve/filter from the funnel of a moka pot?

Tags: moka

I often buy used pots for my little collection and want to give them a thorough cleaning. However, removing the sieve is a PITA with the crimp that is there holding it in. Note that I am not talking about the sieve that is held in place by the gasket. That is simple enough to remove. However, the funnel sieve is more difficult to remove without bending it badly. I've been turning the funnel upside down and pushing the end of a beater (from and electric beater) into it and pushing it out. However, that takes some force, resulting in a bent sieve. There has to be a better way.

Comment: There are videos online of people using screwdrivers or similar to push out the top of funnel, but as you say it may be destructive, particularly on smaller models. Alternatively, straw cleaner brushes can be used. I agree it's disappointing.